# Most Efficient Code for clipping the elements of a vector until it reaches a sum

Tags: python, numpy, vector

Suppose we have an integer vector that sums to `S1`.  I would like to take this vector, and produce another vector that sums to `S2<S1`.  I'd like to do this by subtracting off the (first) max element one by one until the sum is down below 4.

E.g. `clip_by_sum([1,4,8,3], total=10) == [1, 3, 3, 3]`.

An easy code which does this is:

```
def clip_to_sum(vec, total):
    new_vec = np.array(vec)  
    current_total = np.sum(vec)
    while current_total > total:
        i = np.argmax(new_vec)
        new_vec[i] -= 1
        current_total -= 1
    return new_vec
```

However, it's obviously horribly inefficient, because we only subtract off one element at a time no matter how much the lead vector is leading by.

Anyone have a nifty trick for doing this efficiently?

**Edit**: An input vector that already sums to less than `S1` can be left unchanged, so for example `clip_to_sum([1,4,8,3], 20)` should be `[1,4,8,3]`

**Edit** For those wondering what this is for, it's for the mundane task of determining column widths in a fixed-width table!

Comment: What's `clip_by_sum`? With `clip_to_sum([1,4,8,3], total=10)`, I am getting `10`.

Comment: What are the characteristics of your typical `vec` and `total`?  That is, typically, what is `len(vec)`, what is the range of values in `vec`, and what is a typical value for `total`?

Comment: @Divakar - that was a mistake and I corrected the function now.  @Warren no particular characteristics in mind, it should just not have extremely slow run times in certain situations (this version for example would run extremely slowly for `clip_to_sum([2, int(1e10)], total=1e5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two functions that compute the clipped array.  The first, `limit_sum1`, will not give exactly the same result as your function, because it, in effect, makes different choices of which "max" to decrease when the the maximum occurs multiple times in the input vector.  That is, if `vec = [4, 4, 4]`, and `total = 11`, there are three possible results: `[3, 4, 4]`, `[4, 3, 4]`, and `[4, 4, 3]`.  Your function gives `[3, 4, 4]`, while `limit_sum1` gives `[4, 4, 3]`.

For very small input vectors, like the examples in the question, `limit_sum2` is generally faster than `limit_sum1`, but neither is faster than your `clip_to_sum`. For somewhat longer input vectors with more varied input range, both are faster than `clip_to_sum`, and for very long input vectors, `limit_sum1` is *much* faster.  Examples with timing are below.

```
def limit_sum1(vec, total):
    x = np.asarray(vec)
    delta = x.sum() - total
    if delta <= 0:
        return x

    i = np.argsort(x)

    # j is the inverse of the sorting permutation i.
    j = np.empty_like(i)
    j[i] = np.arange(len(x))[::-1]

    y = np.zeros(len(x)+1, dtype=int)
    y[1:] = x[i]

    d = np.diff(y)[::-1]
    y = y[::-1]

    wd = d * np.arange(1, len(d)+1)
    cs = wd.cumsum()

    k = np.searchsorted(cs, delta, side='right')
    if k > 0:
        y[:k] -= d[:k][::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
        delta = delta - cs[k-1]

    q, r = divmod(delta, k+1)

    y[:k+1] -= q
    y[:r] -= 1

    x2 = y[j]
    return x2


def limit_sum2(vec, total):
    a = np.array(vec)
    while a.sum() > total:
        amax = a.max()
        i = np.where(a == amax)[0]
        if len(i) < len(a):
            nextmax = a[a < amax].max()
        else:
            nextmax = 0
        clip_to_nextmax_delta = len(i)*(amax - nextmax)
        diff = a.sum() - total
        if clip_to_nextmax_delta > diff:
            q, r = divmod(diff, len(i))
            a[i] -= q
            a[i[:r]] -= 1
            break
        else:
            # Clip all the current max values to nextmax.
            a[i] = nextmax
    return a
```

Examples

```
In [1388]: vec = np.array([1, 4, 8, 3])
```

`limit_sum1`, `limit_sum2` and `clip_to_sum` all give the same result:

```
In [1389]: limit_sum1(vec, total=10)
Out[1389]: array([1, 3, 3, 3])

In [1390]: limit_sum2(vec, total=10)
Out[1390]: array([1, 3, 3, 3])

In [1391]: clip_to_sum(vec, total=10)
Out[1391]: array([1, 3, 3, 3])
```

`clip_to_sum` is faster with this small vector.

```
In [1392]: %timeit limit_sum1(vec, total=10)
33.1 µs ± 272 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [1393]: %timeit limit_sum2(vec, total=10)
24.6 µs ± 138 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [1394]: %timeit clip_to_sum(vec, total=10)
15.6 µs ± 44.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Let's try a longer vector containing bigger values.

```
In [1405]: np.random.seed(1729)

In [1406]: vec = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=50)

In [1407]: vec
Out[1407]: 
array([13, 37, 21, 67, 13, 89, 59, 35, 65, 91, 36, 73, 93, 83, 43, 86, 44,
       19, 51, 76, 12, 26, 43,  0, 42, 53, 30, 65,  3, 65, 37, 68, 64, 87,
       91,  4, 70, 10, 50, 40, 34, 32, 13,  7, 93, 79, 16, 98,  1, 35])

In [1408]: vec.sum()
Out[1408]: 2362
```

Find a result using each function:

```
In [1409]: limit_sum1(vec, total=1500)
Out[1409]: 
array([13, 37, 21, 38, 13, 38, 38, 35, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38,
       19, 38, 38, 12, 26, 38,  0, 39, 38, 30, 38,  3, 38, 37, 38, 38, 38,
       38,  4, 38, 10, 38, 39, 34, 32, 13,  7, 38, 38, 16, 38,  1, 35])

In [1410]: limit_sum2(vec, total=1500)
Out[1410]: 
array([13, 37, 21, 38, 13, 38, 38, 35, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38,
       19, 38, 38, 12, 26, 38,  0, 38, 38, 30, 38,  3, 38, 37, 38, 38, 38,
       38,  4, 38, 10, 38, 38, 34, 32, 13,  7, 38, 39, 16, 39,  1, 35])

In [1411]: clip_to_sum(vec, total=1500)
Out[1411]: 
array([13, 37, 21, 38, 13, 38, 38, 35, 38, 38, 36, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38,
       19, 38, 38, 12, 26, 38,  0, 38, 38, 30, 38,  3, 38, 37, 38, 38, 38,
       38,  4, 38, 10, 38, 38, 34, 32, 13,  7, 38, 39, 16, 39,  1, 35])
```

This time, `limit_sum1` is the fastest by a wide margin:

```
In [1413]: %timeit limit_sum1(vec, total=1500)
34.9 µs ± 257 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [1414]: %timeit limit_sum2(vec, total=1500)
272 µs ± 2.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [1415]: %timeit clip_to_sum(vec, total=1500)
1.74 ms ± 7.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I think this warren guy got it.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically going *Robin Hood* there and clipping off the values that are above global average w.r.t. `total`, until the global sum reaches a threshold. Using that theory, we will start off with a baseline number and then loop through, like so -

```
def clip_until_sum(vec, total):
    # Get array version
    a = np.asarray(vec)  

    if a.sum() <= total: 
        return a

    # Baseline number
    b = int(total/float(len(a)))

    # Setup output
    out = np.where(a > b, b, a)
    s = out.sum()

    # Loop to shift up values starting from baseline
    while s<total:
        idx = np.flatnonzero(a > out)
        dss = total - s
        out[idx[max(0,len(idx)-dss):]] += 1
        s = out.sum()
    return out
```

Sample runs -

Set #1 :

```
In [868]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 10)
Out[868]: array([1, 3, 3, 3])

In [869]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 11)
Out[869]: array([1, 3, 4, 3])

In [870]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 12)
Out[870]: array([1, 4, 4, 3])

In [871]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 13)
Out[871]: array([1, 4, 5, 3])

In [872]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 14)
Out[872]: array([1, 4, 6, 3])

In [873]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 15)
Out[873]: array([1, 4, 7, 3])

In [874]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3], 16)
Out[874]: array([1, 4, 8, 3])
```

Set #2 :

```
In [875]: clip_until_sum([1,4,8,3,5,6], 12)
Out[875]: array([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

Runtime test and verification -

```
In [164]: np.random.seed(0)

# Assuming 10000 elems with max of 1000 and total as half of sum
In [165]: vec = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=10000)

In [167]: total = vec.sum()//2

In [168]: np.allclose(clip_to_sum(vec, total), clip_until_sum(vec, total))
Out[168]: True

In [169]: %timeit clip_to_sum(vec, total)
1 loop, best of 3: 19.1 s per loop

In [170]: %timeit clip_until_sum(vec, total)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.8 ms per loop

# @Warren Weckesser's soln
In [171]: %timeit limit_sum1(vec, total)
1000 loops, best of 3: 733 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice approach... one trouble is the while-loop never terminates if total exceeds the sum of the vector ie. `clip_to_sum([1,4,8,3], 20)` never stops.  It also looks like the run-time of the approach would scale with the magnitude of the vectors (since we're just adding back 1 on each loop)

Comment: @Peter What's the expected output for `clip_to_sum([1,4,8,3], 20)`? If it is `[1,4,8,3]`, we can simply get the sum and check against `total` and short circuit at the start.

Comment: @Peter Yes, if there are a lot of variations (large numbers and small numbers), then the runtime would grow.

Comment: `clip_to_sum([1,4,8,3], 20)` should be `[1,4,8,3]`, so that's an easy fix, just need a check before the loop

Comment: @Peter Yes, something like `if a.sum() <= total: return a`.

Comment: With `vec = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, `clip_until_sum(vec, total=25)` gives `array([4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])`.  Shouldn't the result be `array([5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Good catch! Thanks for checking back. Edited with the fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your function to include a difference between the max and second max elements. This will use additional compute resources per loop but should reduce the total number of loops significantly.

I've tested this versus your original function and it gives the same results. Though, admittedly, I am having difficulty seeing any real speed up between the two.

```
def clip_to_sum(vec, total):
    current_total = np.sum(vec)
    new_vec = np.array(vec)
    while current_total > total:
        i = np.argmax(new_vec)
        d = np.partition(new_vec.flatten(), -2)[-2]
        diff = new_vec[i] - d
        if not (new_vec[i] == diff) and diff > 0:
          new_vec[i] -= diff
          current_total -= diff
        else:
          new_vec[i] -= 1
          current_total -= 1
    return new_vec
```

Comment: Nice.  That's works - much better for a vector with large values.  But it looks like it remains a bit inefficient when you have a long  vector with lots of similar values (because it  does a new argmax and partial sort each time).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it's not realy obvious what type of result you are interested in. But let's assume you have an array of a certain length and you want to take out the first elements A[0:ix] so that the sum is (somehow close to) S1, you can do:

```
S1 = 5
A = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,])

B = np.cumsum(A)
ix = np.argmax(B>=S1)+1
C = A[0:ix]
print("C = ", C); print("sum C = ", np.sum(C))
```

which gives

```
C =  [1 1 1 1 1]
sum C =  5
```

You can write the same in 1 line

```
C = A[0:np.argmax(np.cumsum(A)>=S1)+1]
```

Comment: The aim of this question is not to clip the length of the vector, but the magnitude of the maximum elements.  See example in original question